# trying to install requests module using pip and python 3.4

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

After fumbling online for a bit, I learned that python 3.4 now comes with pip ready installed. I installed python 3.4 and plan on installing **requests** through the command line. I tried the following

```
>>> pip install requests
File "<stdin>", line 1
pip install requests
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


>>> sudo pip install requests
File "<stdin>", line 1
sudo pip install requests
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

They all return the same error. I'm still learning python, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `pip` is not a Python command. You need to type this in *on the command line*, not in Python.

Comment: sorry if it's unclear, but I typed this in the "Python (command line)". Isn't that the same as normal windows command prompt, but with python?

Comment: No, it is not. The Python interactive shell only runs Python code, not Windows commands.

Comment: when i run this in cmd.exe, it returns "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: It comes with Python 3.4, but you call it as `py -3 -m pip install` instead, see https://docs.python.org/3.4/installing/index.html.

Comment: now it's saying "python is not recognized as an internal or external command..... " What is generally the cause of this error?

Comment: My comment was updated. Do read the linked documentation, it explains things is some more detail than fits in a comment.

Comment: I see, thank you ! Sorry, I'll start getting into the habits of looking at docs